# Symfony - How to call a controller from within a Listener?

Tags: symfony, listener

I have an **Repas** (meal) entity in which every baby's meal is recorded.

I have a **Jour** (day) entity that stores totals and other relevant information.

Every time a *Repas* is added or updated, I want to update the *Jour* entity.
In can do that in the *RepasController.php*. But, in order to be DRY I want to prevent code duplication in add() and update() methods. Therefore, I've create a *RepasListener*.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to call a method inside JourController from wihin my listener.

Any help?

Comment: I exactly don't know how to reach you goal or if it is possible. My recommendation is read https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html

Comment: Calling a controller from a listener is bad practice, if even possible. You can create a service that handles the logic and inject it in both your controller method and your event listener.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i'll do a doctrine event https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html  on Repas and see if it's a new one update Jour (and with this event you will also loose your controller code).